# CP2K geometry optimization SCF takes 3000s for a step

Tags: geometry-optimization, cp2k, energy-conversion

I am new to CP2K and doing a geometry optimization for a cluster. At the beginning everything looks good, each SCF step takes about 13 seconds, the energy drops quickly and the convergence looks like it converges in a few steps.
But after some time, the SCF step time quickly increased to a few hundred seconds and then to 3000 seconds. I checked everything but found no error.[image]

Could you please provide me with some advise, thank you !

Best,
Jessie

Comment: Please provide your CP2K input.